# Combination of all values (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, combinations

I would like to get all possible combinations from a given data set, but even with empty elements (i.e. with a variable number of elements)

Example we have data and a simple query that displays them:

```
with t as (   select 1 as COL1, 2 as COL2, 3 as COL3 from dual )  
select * from t;
```

or better example: (perhaps simple to solve)

```
select 1 as col from dual 
union all 
select 2 from dual 
union all 
select 3 from dual
```

Is it possible to create a query that displays the following result:

```
1     -     -
1     2     -
1     2     3
1     3     -
1     3     2

2     -     -
2     1     -
2     1     3
2     3     -
2     3     1

3     -     -
3     1     -
3     1     2
3     2     -
3     2     1
```

Comment: For completeness, shouldn't the output also have a row where ALL THREE columns are null? (I assume by the dash you mean NULL, but please clarify either way.)

Comment: By the way, the correct technical term for what you are asking, in combinatorics (a branch of mathematics), is *arrangements*, not combinations. Arrangements are ordered, combinations are not. (1,3) is a different arrangement from (3,1) (because the order is different), but they are the same combinations - they consist of the same elements of the original set.

Comment: That's what I mean by "-" I mean null.)

Comment: All three should not be null, because then they would have to be two and one null ;) And that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

One difficulty here is that you have the inputs in three columns and you want the results in three columns. Unless you are willing to use dynamic SQL (which is a separate topic, an advanced technique which is also a bad practice in most cases and has really nothing to do with your question about combinatorics) you will have to hard-code the number (and names) of columns in the query.

You could present the input data in rows rather than columns, and ask for the result in the format

```
row_num  col_num  val
-------  -------  ---
      1        1    1
      1        2    -
      1        3    -
```

(this mimics just your first output row) - and similar for all other rows - and then you would NOT have to hard-code the number of columns in the query; you could then easily adapt the code below to solve this more general problem.

I use `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` below, which limits the number of columns (and the length of values in each column in the input); this can be avoided, but writing the query this way is fun.

I assumed the dash `-` in your desired output stands for `NULL`; if you actually want to show dashes, use `NVL(..., -)` in the final `SELECT` clause.

```
with
  t (col1, col2, col3) as (
    select 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 3 as col3 from dual
  )
, prep (pth) as (
    select  sys_connect_by_path(val, '/') || '/' 
    from    t 
    unpivot (val for col in (col1, col2, col3))
    connect by nocycle prior col is not null
  )
select to_number(substr(pth, instr(pth, '/', 1, 1) + 1, 
                        instr(pth, '/', 1, 2) - instr(pth, '/', 1, 1) - 1)) col1,
       to_number(substr(pth, instr(pth, '/', 1, 2) + 1, 
                        instr(pth, '/', 1, 3) - instr(pth, '/', 1, 2) - 1)) col2,
       to_number(substr(pth, instr(pth, '/', 1, 3) + 1, 
                        instr(pth, '/', 1, 4) - instr(pth, '/', 1, 3) - 1)) col3
from   prep
order  by col1 nulls first, col2 nulls first, col3 nulls first
;
```

Output:

```
 COL1  COL2  COL3
----- ----- -----
    1            
    1     2      
    1     2     3
    1     3      
    1     3     2
    2            
    2     1      
    2     1     3
    2     3      
    2     3     1
    3            
    3     1      
    3     1     2
    3     2      
    3     2     1
```

Comment: so there is a problem with three columns, but of course the source of data can be in the rows - and that would be better. That is (select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3 from dual). Is it possible to write a simple query for the data case in lines?

Comment: @TomaszTomzik - the biggest complication is with the output. Do you need it in "n" columns, where "n" is only known after you inspect the input data? If so, that can't be done with static SQL. Would the output presented in the way I show in my answer (**in the first part, at the top**) work for you?